# Tk/Tcl scale widget interval issue

Tags: tcl, scale, resolution

I'm building a scale widget going from 10 to 100 with a spacing (interval) of 10.
When the resolution=1 the result is:
[scale widget with resolotion=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNUTx.jpg)

But when the resolution=3 the scale is going from 9 to 99 and no more 10->100,
the results is showed here:
[scale widget with resolution=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj1ii.jpg)

The code is:

```
#!/bin/sh
####################################################################### \
exec /sw/freetools/tk/8.5.6/Linux/rh5/x86_64/bin/wish8.5 "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Tk

font create FONT1 -family {DejaVu Sans Mono} -size 7 -weight normal
font create FONT2 -family {DejaVu Sans} -size -8 -weight normal -slant roman

ttk::style configure rule1.TCombobox -background lavender \
                                     -foreground black \
                                     -fieldbackground mistyrose2 \
                                     -padding 0.5
ttk::style map rule1.TCombobox       -fieldbackground [list readonly gray98]

frame .frame_F1        -background gray98 -highlightbackground black -highlightthickness 1 
frame .frame_F1.top    -background gray98 -highlightbackground red   -highlightthickness 0
frame .frame_F1.bottom -background gray98 -highlightbackground blue  -highlightthickness 0

pack .frame_F1 -padx 10 -pady 10
pack .frame_F1.top    -side top -anchor w
pack .frame_F1.bottom -side bottom -anchor w

label .frame_F1.bottom.scale_text1 -text "scale" -foreground black -background gray98 -font FONT1 -justify left
entry .frame_F1.bottom.scale_value -textvariable ::SCALE      -foreground black -width 5 -justify right -state readonly

scale .frame_F1.top.scale -orient horizontal \
                          -variable ::SCALE \
                          -length 210 \
                          -from 10 -to 100 \
                          -tickinterval 10 \
                          -resolution 1 \
                          -showvalue false \
                          -background gray98 \
                          -font FONT2 \
                          -foreground black \
                          -width 12 \
                          -highlightthickness 0 \
                          -borderwidth 2 \
                          -sliderrelief groove \
                          -sliderlength 18

pack .frame_F1.top.scale
grid .frame_F1.bottom.scale_text1  -column 0 -row 1
grid .frame_F1.bottom.scale_value  -column 1 -row 1
```

How to correct this and to have from 10 to 100 ?

Comment: Cannot duplicate.  Did you make any other changes other than `-resolution 3` ?

Comment: Using -resolution 5 is ok.
Using -resolution 2 is keeping the 10/100.
Using -resolution 4 is changing the value to 12->96 but it has the 100 at the end.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when using a range whose size isn't an integer multiple of the step size?